# How to setup/configure Appium on Mac to run iOS tests from Visual Studio using C#

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2012, appium

I've installed Appium and xcode on my Macbook Pro. On VM I have Visual Studio and code written in C#. I need to figure out how to make Visual Studio on VM communicate with the Appium server on Mac.

Answer (score 0):

I think I managed. The problem was with the IP address. 127.0.0.1 is local. I needed to change the IP address I was trying to connect to the IP of the Macbook Pro.

Comment: I know this is old but if you could show examples of what you did I would love to see them.